# How can I make a basic Java window with a text field and a button using JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

I tried to find some code from the internet and copy-pasted it (i also tried making my own code from the java documentation, but it gave some errors i didnt understand, i have jdk installed), but when i typed "javac program.java" it did not output a file.

Comment: Use an IDE. You can choose either Eclipse (you need to do more work) or NetBeans (you are more limited in the editing of the forms), but, for learning, probably Eclipse is better. Those IDEs have a lot of tools to help you finding errors and correcting them. Use javac only if strictly required.

Comment: thanks! i was using vs code but i'll try to switch to eclipse

Comment: If you are not setting up a menu bar or creating special windowing functionality, the best place to start is with a JPanel (because you can then put the JPanel into a Window/Dialog/Frame)

Comment: Just be warned that Eclipse has problems with the last JDK (18). I think it works with JDK 16. But, if you're doing it for school, Eclipse is the best choice.

Comment: You don't explain what errors you're getting so it's hard to tell what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleUI {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    var frame = new JFrame("Title goes here");
    var text = new JTextField(20);
    var button = new JButton("Click me");
    var panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Creates:

[image]

More info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html